# Aggregate xml and list of xmls

Tags: xml, apache-camel, aggregate

I want to aggregate a group of xmls. First I will show the end result that I want to get

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<order>
    <header>
        <name>something</name>
        <age>321321</age>
    </header>

    <message>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>some name</name>
        <content>some content</content>
    </message>

    <message>
        <id>2</id>
        <name>some name</name>
        <content>some content</content>
    </message>

    <message>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>some name</name>
        <content> some content</content>
    </message>
</order>
```

Ok so I have spliter that return me xmls like this:

```
<header>
    <name>something</name>
    <age>321321</age>
</header>
```

and

```
    <message>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>some name</name>
        <content>some content</content>
    </message>
```

and

```
    <message>
        <id>3</id>
        <name>some name</name>
        <content>some content</content>
    </message>
```

I mean by this that I return me a subtags. How can I aggregate it again into one like first xml?

is my question clear?

Comment: No. The question is not clear :-) Can you give an example with what you will obtain ? Is that some XML tags that aggregate some other values found in other tags as counting number of message or returning maximum message number ? How to you will aggregate XML tags ? using Java ? using XSLT ? using XPath ?

Comment: Well I want to do something like first split document then add something in value of one tag then aggregate again, but I don't know how to aggregate it..

Comment: I understand that you don't know how to aggregate it and that you wait some help. But I propose that you make a better example because the first split doesn't contains any aggregation. The first split (with <header> tag is only a filter of Main XML file. I propose that you make an example of aggregation using a counter or for extracting a minimum or maximum value or for summing some values.|

Comment: You can do this with a single XLST no splitting needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you initially splitted the XML, do something with the parts and now you want to re-aggregate the modified parts, you just need to extend your splitter.

The [Splitter EIP](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/split-eip.adoc) is able to "automatically" aggregate the split parts when you give it an aggregation strategy. See [this part](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/split-eip.adoc#split-aggregate-requestreply-sample) (section "Split aggregate request/reply sample") of the Splitter docs for an example.

So the use case is: you split a document into 10 parts, modify each part somehow and the re-aggregate the 10 modified parts back to a single document.